# Databricks notebook multicursor

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, databricks

I would like to use Multicursor feature in Databricks notebook but I couldn't find one. Does this support it? Is there a plugin for it?

I look at IntelliJ Idea Multi-line editing feature as a perfect example:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Multicursor.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an option to get multiple cursor with Ctrl + alt + mouse left long click on all the lines that you want to select.

Comment: `⌘ + [option] + click` if you're on a mac